# Redux- mapStateToProps not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react component that makes an AJAX call in componentWillMount and backs the data received in response to a redux store. Here is code

```
componentWillMount() {
  var self = this;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
      var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var data = {
        json
      };
      self.props.dispatch({
        type: "ADD_Exams",
        data
      });
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/getExams/", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In the reducer, I am assigning the data received in action to an array defined in the reducer state.

```
const initialState = {
  exams:[]    
}

const examreducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_Exams":
      return {
        ...state,
        exams: [...state.exams, action.data.json]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But when I use mapStateToProps to read exams variable I get undefined.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        exams: state.exams
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Exam);
```

I am creating store like this

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
const store = createStore(loginReducer, examReducer);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Exam />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

console.log(this.props.exams) prints undefined. What is the problem here?

Comment: where is the console.log in your code?

Comment: prints "/static/media/examReducer.d41d8cd9.bin" on console.

Comment: how do you initialize the store?

Comment: its inside the render function of the component

Comment: By calling createStore like this 
const store = createStore(loginReducer,examReducer);

Comment: @saim2025 where do you get `createStore` function from? how does it look?

Answer (score 21):

I ran into the same problem. My mistake was because I was doing wrong export/import of the component.

export:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component
...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

import:

```
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
```

to solve I removed the export on the class and used the default:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
```

Comment: Please go deeper and explain why the problem is happening. For example, talk about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: This just put an end to my 4 hours of trying to knock my head around redux, thunk and store stuff.

Comment: thanks mate, this was my exact problem, intelliJ auto-imported it with { AbcComponent }, solved by using the default component which is the one that is connected to Redux! :)

Answer (score 11):

I spent countless hours finding what was wrong, why my props werent getting any information.

I followed @Romain Pellerin and was able to discovered something

I originally had my mapStateToProps like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {


  return {
      userInfo: state.userInfo,
      loading: state.loading,
      error: state.error
  };
```

}

Following Romain's answer, i console logged and watched the output of my state object, and found that i had to specify the specific reducer that had the state that i needed to access! Because i had used combineReducers, maybe you have to specify which reducer you want to access in mapStateToProps. Soo i had to change my code to this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);

    return {
        userInfo: state.THE_SPECIFIC_REDUCER.userInfo,
        loading: state.THE_SPECIFIC_REDUCER.loading,
        error: state.THE_SPECIFIC_REDUCER.error
    };
}
```

Heres my code where i combine the reducers:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loginReducer,
  THE_SPECIFIC_REDUCER
});
```

Soo, given that i was trying to get "THE_SPECIFIC_REDUCER" state, i had to specify it in the mapStateToProps like this:

```
myProp: state.THE_SPECIFIC_REDUCER.theThingIWantToAccess
```

I hope this works for someone!

Comment: You have saved me hours of frustration. Thank you Luis!

Comment: awesome, this should be an accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Can you edit your `mapStateToProps` like this to see the actual content of your state?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   console.log(state);
    return {
        exams: state.exams
    }
}
```

I suspect your reducer is not at the root of your reducers. If so, you might need to do `state.examreducer.exams`.
Also, is your component wrapped a in `Provider`? You need it to access the context (through which your state is accessible).

**UPDATE**

Make sure to initialize your store before rendering any React component.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(combineReducers({loginReducer, examReducer}), {loginReducer:{}, examReducer:{}});
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Exam />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Then update your `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        exams: state.examReducer.exams || []
    }
}
```

Comment: prints "/static/media/examReducer.d41d8cd9.bin" to console

Comment: How is that possible? Can you show a screenshot of the console please?

Comment: createStore has another args

Comment: import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
const store = createStore(loginReducer,examReducer);
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
<Exam />
</Provider>,document.getElementById("root"));

registerServiceWorker();
I am doing this

Comment: exams: state.examReducer.exams results in "Cannot read the property of undefined error"

Comment: Use this store: `const store = createStore(combineReducers({loginReducer, examReducer}), {loginReducer:{}, examReducer:{}});`

Comment: still  the same issue

Comment: Can you `console.log(state)` in your `mapStateToProps` and copy the output please?

Answer (score 3):

I think there's an issue in how you retrieve data or initialize store. Try this:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import loginReducer from '../path';
import examReducer from '../path';

const rootStore = combineReducers({
  loginReducer,
  examReducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Exam />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and then:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        exams: state.examReducer.exams
    }
}
```